# What is this fantasy style card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

A few years ago I was with a group of people. Someone brought a fantasy style card game. I can't remember much, but the main thing I can remember is that you could equip your own armor, weapons and tools. You had to put your cards on the table so that the weapon in your right hand goes to the one side of your armor and the off hand tool/weapon goes on the other side. I think there was other stuff like a helmet that goes above and pants that go under the chest peace and every weapon/armor/tool had his own perks. With all that you had to fight other cards with monsters or something on it.

I've been searching for a long time, but I think it wasn't a popular card game.

Comment: Maybe [Munchkin](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1927/munchkin)? (I know you said it might not be popular, but just in case...)

Comment: "every card had his own *perks*" - definitely Munchkin

Answer (score 4):

This absolutely sounds like [Munchkin](https://munchkin.game/products/games/munchkin/) or one of the many versions of it by Steve Jackson, and if so it definitely IS a popular game. Equipment cards, monsters, curses and some form of class cards are common to all the versions, many equipment have special restrictions or buffs on top of the basic number bonus, and you use them (and potentially help from other players) to fight monsters with the goal of getting to level 10 first.

[image: Munchkin Cards]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the New Zealand TCG *Flesh and Blood* (https://fabtcg.com/)
4 Armor slots with different effects are used.
If you've seen the playmat, the Head is above the Chest and Arms with the Feet below that
[image: on the left]

You also play a hero with a dedicated weapon while drawing hands from your Deck.
Hope this helps!:)

Edit: The game came out in October 2019, so if you're remembering an event earlier than that, you can rule out this answer

Comment: Sounds interesting, but based on that playmate the weapons aren't on either side of the armor as the question specifies. (Doesn't mean this is wrong, could just be them being taught a differnt card layout without a mat)